# Collection empty magento

Tags: php, magento

Hello my collection is not being populated with the values from the database on my local machine is running, but in non-production environment.
When I run the generated SQL values are normally shown in the bank, but the collection is not populated. Can you help me?

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $userid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $rowdata=array();

    $querydata = Mage::getModel('stock/product')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('userid', array('eq' => $userid))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => 2))
        ->setOrder('stockproductid');

    foreach ($querydata as  $value) {
        $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
            ->loadByProduct($value->getStockproductid())->getQty();
        if($qty) {
            $rowdata[] = $value->getStockproductid();
        }
    }

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $rowdata));
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');

    //filter with search content
    if(!empty($post)) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'name', 'like'=>'%'.$post['searchfr'].'%')));
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got flat catalog enabled?
My guess would be try to reindex on your production environment.

Comment: I've reindexei, but nothing changes.

Comment: Please, someone can help me?